# Handling multiple key events libgdx

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

I am trying to make a game using the libgdx framework.
I am using an InputAdapter to check for key press events, everything works fine until more than 3 keys are pressed at once.
I need 3 or more than 3 key events if player is moving diagonally and shooting at the same time.
For some reason the input adapter only registers first 2 key events and no new press event is registered until one of the keys is up.

```
public class MyInputProcessor extends InputAdapter{

public boolean keyDown(int k)
{
    switch (k)
    {


        case Keys.LEFT:
        MyInput.setKey(MyInput.LEFT, true);
        break;

        case Keys.UP:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.UP, true);

            break;
        case Keys.DOWN:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.DOWN, true);

            break;
        case Keys.RIGHT:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.RIGHT, true);

            break;
        case Keys.Z:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.SHOOT, true);

            break;
        case Keys.ESCAPE:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.ESC, true);

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
public boolean keyUp(int k)
{
    switch (k)
    {


        case Keys.LEFT:
        MyInput.setKey(MyInput.LEFT, false);
        break;

        case Keys.UP:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.UP, false);
            break;
        case Keys.DOWN:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.DOWN, false);
            break;
        case Keys.RIGHT:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.RIGHT, false);
            break;
        case Keys.Z:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.SHOOT, false);
            break;
        case Keys.ESCAPE:
            MyInput.setKey(MyInput.ESC, false);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: This is probably not a libgdx problem, but a problem with your keyboard. Most keyboards don't recognize key-combinations with more than 3 keys, or only with certain keys.

Comment: that seems to be the reason! thanks!  :)

Comment: whoever comes across same problem, try a different sets of keys. I had porblem while using 'Z' along with arrow keys, but 'X' works fine!. hope this helps.